# Использование имени из шаблонного наследника в MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++, наследование

Почему этот код [компилируется](https://godbolt.org/z/f8739j) компилятором *x64 msvc v19.24* с опциями `/std:c++17 /Wall /W4` без предупреждений? Это баг? Можно ли как-то заставить выдавать хотя бы предупреждение, типа опции `-pedantic` в *gcc*?

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    int x = 42;
};

template <typename T>
struct B : A<T> {
    int f() { 
        return x;
    }
};

int main() {
    B<int> b;
    b.f();
}
```

Comment: Компилятор VC++ 2019 (16.6.4), `/std:c++17` выдает `test.cpp(9): error C3861: x: идентификатор не найден`. То же самое - и в VC++ 2017 (15.9.25).

Comment: @Harry версия 16.6.4 из той же нумерации, что и v19.24 у godbolt-а, или это вообще разные вещи? Тестировал только на сайте, а там 16.6.4 нет

Comment: Не знаю, видимо, это что-то разное... По крайней мере 16.6.4 - вроде бы последняя. И что такое 19.24 - не знаю...

Comment: @Harry я думаю, что ваша версия - это `VS Version`, а из godbolt - `MSVC compiler version` из таблички отсюда https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-conformance-improvements-in-visual-studio-2017-version-15-5/

Comment: На версии VS 16.6.5 компилятор 19.26.28806 код компилируется без ошибок. У него нет обязательной компиляции шаблонов, поэтому все ОК.

Comment: @AndreySv так должны быть ошибки. Или объясните, почему не должны

Comment: Когда шаблон инстанциируется то все данные есть и можно корректно компилировать. А до этого момента можете там любую ахиненю писать. https://godbolt.org/z/91nM9a

Comment: @AndreySv так тут есть инстанциация. И даже тот код, который вы привели, считается некорректным, хоть и может компилироваться

Comment: Другие компиляторы пытаются компилировать до инстанциирования. Поменяйте компилятор и все увидите https://godbolt.org/z/rb4e4Y

Comment: @AndreySv я не понимаю, как это доказывает, что ошибок быть не должно. Вы же сами говорите, что другие компиляторы показывают ошибки

Comment: Я просто говорю почему это происходит и что предварительная компиляция шаблона дает такой эффект и при недостаточной информации дает ошибку даже там где ее нет.

Comment: [опция /permissive тоже не меняет все](https://godbolt.org/z/aoWzYM)

Comment: @user7860670 действительно, если указать `/permissive-` вместо `/permissive`, то ошибка есть, спасибо. Интересно, почему не было предупреждения о неизвестной опции тогда? Осталось узнать ответы на остальные вопросы

Comment: `/permissive` включает permissive режим `/permissive-` выключает его

Comment: @user7860670 понял, буду знать. Если знаете ответ на первый вопрос тоже, то давайте ответ - приму

Comment: на первый - это на какой?

Comment: @user7860670 почему этот код компилируется без этого флага? Это баг?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это нестандартное поведение. В компиляторе msvc долгое время не был реализован двухфазный поиск имен, но потом его добавили, а чтобы не ломать старые приложения старое поведение оставили в permissive режиме. Соответственно аргумент `/permissive-` среди прочего выключает это старое поведение и заставлять компилятор компилировать в соответствии со стандартом и [выдавать на этом примере ошибку](https://godbolt.org/z/aoWzYM).

[Microsoft C++ language conformance table](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Насколько я понял по [этому посту](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-conformance-improvements-in-visual-studio-2017-version-15-5/) **We’ve enabled the `/permissive-` conformance mode by default with new projects created in Visual C++** этот флаг должен выставляться по умолчанию, но почему-то в godbolt-е он не выставляется. Стоит ли писать им баг-репорт или тут имеется в виду что-то другое?

Comment: @dIm0n godbolt же не создает проект, а вызывает сам компилятор

Comment: Но там же есть дефолтные флаги, почему они этот флаг не включили

Comment: @dIm0n потому что тогда бы поломалась сборка старых проектов

Comment: Не, я имею в виду дефолтные флаги в godbolt-е. Их можно посмотреть, когда на галочку нажимаешь слева от флагов. Вот туда по-моему стоит добавить `/permissive-`, раз Microsoft решил сделать его дефолтным

Comment: @dIm0n тогда если кому-то захочется собрать в обычном режиме, то будет предупреждения за повторное указание аргумента https://godbolt.org/z/K39afW